# Optimizing Query with UNION ALL and ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, database-performance

I have 3 tables (ex. a,b,c) which indicates activities for different items (ex. commenting, liking, etc) as well as the time for each activity. I am trying to essentially do a sort of news feed that shows the most recent activities first. I constructed a UNION ALL for all three tables to group all the activities together and then a GROUP BY to ensure that activities for the same items are not shown twice and order by time DESC. This function uses an infinite scroll so the query must also be able to shift appropriately.

I am wondering if there is any way to optimize this (Each table is about 500-900K and growing). Truncated code is shown below.

```
SELECT time,item_id FROM (
   SELECT a.time AS time, a.item_id FROM a 
      UNION ALL 
   SELECT b.time AS time, b.item_id FROM b 
      UNION ALL 
   SELECT c.time AS time, c.item_id FROM c
) temp 
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, this query is non-deterministic: `SELECT time,item_id FROM ... GROUP BY item_id` Here you select a column (`time`) witch is not an aggregate function nor specified in the `GROUP BY` clause. In that case, "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate. " http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html

Answer (score 0):

The query you've written will create a very large temporary table. You're then sorting by a column in that temporary table. You should try to limit each table, perhaps like this:

```
SELECT time,item_id FROM (
   SELECT a.time AS time, a.item_id FROM a LIMIT 10 ORDER BY time DESC 
      UNION ALL 
   SELECT b.time AS time, b.item_id FROM b LIMIT 10 ORDER BY time DESC 
      UNION ALL 
   SELECT c.time AS time, c.item_id FROM c LIMIT 10 ORDER BY time DESC 
) temp 
GROUP BY item_id 
ORDER BY time DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

You'll want to make sure `time` has an index on each table.

I don't really like doing this though, as it may be difficult to "scroll" through the results accurately.

When going to the "next page" you may want to consider adding a `WHERE` clause like `WHERE a/b/c.item_id > num` instead of `LIMIT offset, length`. That will help with the accuracy.

When writing the query you should prefix the query with `EXPLAIN` to see *how* the query is being handled. This will give you a better idea of what's happening: Are temporary tables being created? How large is it? What indexes are being used? etc...

Another approach could be to use a [MySQL trigger](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) to populate a single "feed" table.